# button doesnt seem to change on click in vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to change some button text on a click event. Below is are my methods.

```
 copy() {
            this.$refs.bta.select();
            this.toggleCopy();
            document.execCommand('copy');
        },
        toggleCopy() {
            this.copyButton.text = !this.copyButton.copied
                ? 'copied'
                : 'copy urls';
        },
```

This is my data

```
data() {
        return {
            uglyDomains: [],
            beautifulDomains: [],
            regex: /^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?/i,
            // text areas...
            btaInput: null,
            utaInput: null,

            // buttons
            copyButton: {
                text: 'copy urls',
                copied: false,
            },
        };
    },
```

and here is my button `<button @click="copy">{{ copyButton.text }}</button>`

I believe this to actually work within the dev tools on refresh. But it doesn't seem to work on the actual UI on click. Any ideas?

You can see a working example here: https://beautify-urls.netlify.app/ - I am also trying to clear out the text areas on click of refresh button if anyone can also advise.

Comment: is there any errors in console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the code it seems you never change the  value of `this.copyButton.copied`.

So you should do:

```
    copy() {
        this.$refs.bta.select();
        this.toggleCopy();
        document.execCommand('copy');
    },
    toggleCopy() {
      
        //toggle it here
        this.copyButton.copied = !this.copyButton.copied;
      
        this.copyButton.text = !this.copyButton.copied
            ? 'copied'
            : 'copy urls';
    },
```

Comment: Awesome this kinda works...but it works on a double click on the initial click to copy the urls. I have added a link to the working app above. On the 2nd click it removes the list of clean urls from the textarea...weird.

Comment: I tried your test url and it works for what concerns the question. Please mark as solved so other users can find it helpful.